# atk4 invoke page sub method like in codeignighter controller

Tags: codeigniter, atk4

I have a page:

```
class page_membership extends Page{
   public init(){
      parent::init();
   }

   public register(){

   }

   public reset_password(){

   }
}
```

How do I access from the url to :

```
http://localhost/membership/reset_password
http://localhost/membership/register
```

What are the necessary adjustment I need to do in order to invoke page sub methods like in codeigniter controller?

Thanks

Comment: you can also use page_index and note that "index" is called before any of the page routines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should name your methods `page_register()` and `page_reset_password()` instead.
Doubts are about *reset_password*, because it uses underscore and underscore most likely will be converted to reset/password.

Comment: Interesting. Can u post the htaccess I have tried it as well with success.... Sorry for interacting.

Comment: Use this one for .htaccess: https://github.com/atk4/atk4-secure/blob/master/public/.htaccess

Comment: @DarkSide - if the "page_password" is not found in page/membership/reset, then it will next check for "page_reset_password" in "page/membership.php".

Comment: @romaninsh really? How can that be that I wasn't aware of that... I know what I mixed up. It's file names which can be like membership_reset.php or membership-reset.php, right?